# StoreModule.forRoot in ngrx throws error in angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, store

I need to print data in the store using **ngrx**. but, I'm getting this error while defining `StoreModule.forRoot({customers:reducer})`. In the terminal it says

```
Type '(state: Customer[] | undefined, action: Actions) => Customer[]' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<Customer[], Action>'.
Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Actions'.
Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'RemoveCard'.
```

[image]

Comment: Please share code or share stackblitz example